# JS: function parameters of.then() of an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

When we have an `async` function that returns a variable, and then `.then()` is run...

What does `.then()` accept as parameters?
Is it the variable that `async` returns?

For example, consider this node.js example:

```
const js_package = require('random_js_package');

var random_variable;


let js_function = async () => {
    random_variable = js_package();
    return random_variable;
}


js_function().then((value) => {
    for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++){
        console.log(value[i]);
    }
});
```

In this case, is the variable called `value` inside `.then()` what the `async` function returns?

In other words, is `value` the same as `random_variable`?

Comment: that's correct, yeah.

Comment: If `random_variable` is a value, then `value` will indeed be the same as `random_variable`. If `js_package()` returns Promise, then `value` will be whatever that Promise eventually delivers ... unless the Promises error path is taken, in which case the `.then()` callback won't be called at all; you need to chain `.catch(errorHandler)` in case that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `then` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) accepts two arguments:

1. a function to run if the promise is resolved
2. a function to run if the promise is rejected

The first function you pass to it needs to accept one argument:

1. The resolved value of a promise

Meanwhile, [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) returns:

> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.

---

So, aside from you confusing the `then` function with the function you pass *to* it: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a function with `async` the function will always return a promise. So if you don't explicitly return a promise from the async function then javascript will wrap the value you return in a promise. `.then()` always takes a function which has a parameter which is the resolved value of a promise. So your code is correct the way it is written. In your code `value` will equal `random_variable`. Behind the scenes javascript is returning a promise from `js_function` which is why using `.then((value) =>` works.